# npm ERR! Cannot find module './access-error.js'

Tags: javascript, npm

Anything I try to do with NPM, I end up with `npm ERR! Cannot find module './access-error.js'`. Help!

I first noticed it when trying to install [vue-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs). I ran `npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save` like the docs said to do and got the error:

```
code/premium-poker-tools [master●] » npm install vue-chartjs chart.js --save
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './access-error.js'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamzerner/.npm/_logs/2019-03-12T23_56_46_114Z-debug.log
```

Then I tried installing `chart.js` and `vue-chartjs` individually, but it gives me the same error.

Then I googled the issue. I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30436256/1927876):

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

and it didn't work.

I tried reinstalling NPM and it didn't work. I tried [removing](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/removing-npm.html) NPM via `sudo npm uninstall npm -g` and then planning on reinstalling it after, and it didn't work. Everything I do gives me the `npm ERR! Cannot find module './access-error.js'` error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem sounds very [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876895/unable-to-install-uninstall-anything-using-npm) to one I had a few weeks ago.

What worked for me was removing `Node.js` from my Mac and reinstalling it, because installing `Node.js` installs `npm` as well.

Command used to remove Node.js: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}`

Then just reinstall Node.js and everything should work again!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue.  Was using `Node v8.11.4`.  Switched to `Node v8.9.4` and it started working again...

Using NVM, I did the following:

```
nvm ls 
nvm install <different version>
nvm alias default <different version>
```

Best guess is that it wasn't `8.11` specifically, but something with my particular installation was messed up and using a fresh install fixed it.

Not very satisfying. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Experienced this on Node v13.8 and reverted to Node v12.6.  Resolved with the command sequence above.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Found that the node version is different.
Try the following:
1. `nvm ls`
2. `nvm use <latest version available>`
Now baam .. it works.